# Orthonormal basis of $L^2$ and it's impact on the solution to the heat equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

If we consider the homogeneous Dirichlet eigenvalue problem on a bounded domain $\Omega\subset\Bbb R^n$ - (one part of my question is if we can assume $\Omega$ to be a Lipschitz domain and still expect to be able to solve the eigenvalue problem) - we obtain an orthonormal basis $\{\varphi_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ of $L^2(\Omega)$ consisting of the eigenfunctions. Since $H^1(\Omega)\subset L^2(\Omega)$ we can express a $H^1$ function as an infinite sum of eigenfunctions.

Consider the following three heat equations, (Dirichlet, Neumann, Mixed)

$$\left\{\begin{align}u_t-\Delta u&=f,\quad (x,t)\in\Omega\times(0,T),\\
u&=0,\quad (x,t)\in\partial\Omega\times(0,T),\\
u|_{t=0}&=g,\quad x\in\Omega\end{align}\right.$$

$$\left\{\begin{align}u_t-\Delta u&=f,\quad (x,t)\in\Omega\times(0,T),\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}&=0,\quad (x,t)\in\partial\Omega\times(0,T),\\
u|_{t=0}&=g,\quad x\in\Omega\end{align}\right.$$

$$\left\{\begin{align}u_t-\Delta u&=f,\quad (x,t)\in\Omega\times(0,T),\\
u&=0,\quad (x,t)\in\partial\Omega_1\times(0,T),\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}&=0,\quad (x,t)\in\partial\Omega_2\times(0,T),\\
u|_{t=0}&=g,\quad x\in\Omega\end{align}\right.$$

In the mixed case $\partial\Omega=\partial\Omega_1\cup\partial\Omega_2$, and $n$ is the unit outward normal to whichever boundary portion is in consideration.

The weak formulation to each problem is posed on the space $H^1_0(\Omega)$, $H^1(\Omega)/\Bbb R=\{v\in H^1(\Omega):\int_\Omega v=0\}$, and $H^1_E(\Omega)=\{v\in H^1(\Omega):v|_{\partial\Omega_1}=0\}$, respectively. In this way I can see how the weak solutions differ in nature.

We can use Galerkin approximation to show existence to the three problems, by taking the orthonormal basis $\{\varphi_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ from the eigenvalue problem, and writing the solution $u(x,t)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k(t)\varphi_k$, and approximating by $u^N(x,t)=\sum_{k=1}^N c_k(t)\varphi_k$, plugging this into the weak formulation 
$$\int_\Omega u_t\varphi+\nabla u\cdot\nabla\varphi=\int_\Omega f\varphi$$
for all $\varphi$ in the respective spaces given above, arriving at a system of ODE's for which we determine the values $c_k(t)$, $k=1,\ldots, N$.

From here we have our approximate solution $u^N$, and by obtaining suitable energy estimates, we are allowed to take the limit $N\to\infty$, to obtain the solution $u$.

My question (asides from the necessary domain boundary regularity) is that since the weak formulation is the same, so is the system of PDE's for $c_k(t)$, so in what sense are the solutions to the Dirichlet and mixed Dirichlet-Neumann problem different (the difference between the pure Neumann problem and the others that is clear to me is the fact that the solution integrates to zero)?

To be more concise, it seems that the solutions should satisfy different BC's but the closed form of the solution (written as the sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k(t)\varphi_k$) seems to be the same.

Comment: What problems do the eigenfunctions $\varpi_{k}$ satisfy?

Comment: @TrialAndError, I've consider them all to solve the homogeneous dirichlet eigenvalue problem on $\Omega$

Comment: The eigenfunctions you are using for a particular problem satisfy the homogeneous boundary conditions of that problem, right? That's how the boundary conditions are different. Without such conditions, you don't have an orthonormal basis, but you end up with a union of many orthonormal bases. For the Dirichlet problem, you use the eigenfunctions satisfying the Dirichlet conditions, etc.

Comment: @TrialAndError, but doesn't the galerkin approximation method work even if I take the same Dirichlet eigenvalue problem basis for all problems?

Comment: @TrialAndError I get it now, thanks! Sometimes it takes saying the problem to realise how it works!

Comment: But I am right in thinking we can consider the same eigenvalue problem in each case, but just take different sets $\{\varphi_k\}$ to generate the different respective orthogonal bases?

Comment: Yes, by changing the conditions, you get different eigenvalues and eigenfunctions that are in the domain of the given operator. That's what builds in the homogeneous boundary condition.

Comment: @TrialAndError, what I mean is we can consider the eigenvalue problem $-\Delta u=\lambda u$, $u=0$ on $\partial\Omega$, this gives an orthonormal basis $\{\varphi_k\}$ of $L^2$, then we choose suitable sub-bases to span $H^1/\Bbb R,H^1_0,H^1_E$ and use those. So we don't need to change the eigenvalue problem, just the bases we use?

Comment: What I was saying is that the conditions you stated are just fine for the Dirichlet problem, but the eigenfunctions satisfying Dirichlet conditions are not the in the domain of the Neumann problem. The eigenvalues are not the same either. So a series in the Dirichlet eigenfunctions won't lead to a solution of the Neumann problem.

Comment: @TrialAndError, why is that? If I can still expand any function in any of the spaces as a series of Dirichlet eigenfunctions, why does it not work?

Comment: It is your series that does not work. Let $L_{n}$ be the restriction of $-\Delta$ to the Neumann-condition domain, and $\varphi_{k}$ be a Dirichlet eigenfunction with eigenvalue $\lambda_k$. Suppose $L_{n}u=f$, meaning that $u$ satisfies Neumann conditions. Tell me which step is not valid: $\lambda_{k}(u,\varphi_{k})=(u,L_{d}\varphi_{k})=(f,\varphi_{k})$.

Comment: In each case I assume $\Omega$ is the same, so $\lambda_k(u,\varphi_k)=(u,-\Delta\varphi_k)=(\nabla u,\nabla\varphi_k)=(-\Delta u,\varphi_k)=(f,\varphi_k)$

Comment: $f \Delta^{2}g-\Delta^{2}f g = \nabla\cdot(f\nabla g - \nabla f g)$. So $(L_{d}f,g)-(f,L_{n}g)=\int_{\partial\Omega} f\frac{\partial g}{\partial n}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial n}g dS = -\int_{\partial\Omega}\frac{\partial f}{\partial n}gdS$. The last term is not $0$ in general.

Comment: I think I understand now, so we do not get the desired orthogonality property?

Comment: $\lambda_{k}(u,\varphi_{d,k})=(u,L_{d}\varphi_{d,k})\ne (L_{n}u,\varphi_{d,k})=(f,\varphi_{d,k})$, which keeps you from computing the Fourier coefficients of the solution $u$ of $L_{n}u=f$ in terms of $f$ and of the eigenfunctions $\varphi_{d,k}$.

Comment: @TrialAndError, thanks for the help on this, it really is useful. My final question is if $\Omega$ is a bounded Lipschitz domain is that sufficient smoothness for the eigenfunctions to exist for the mixed problem, and also to allow for higher regularity of the solution (assuming $f,g$ are sufficiently smooth)?

Comment: You'll definitely get higher smoothness from $\Delta u = \lambda u$; Sobolev space theory deals with that case easily. It's the boundary behavior that is in question. For that, Schauder Theory is what you want. I think you need $C^{2,\alpha}$ for $\Omega$ to apply Schauder Theory. Then you get nice smoothness if $Lu=f \in C^{\alpha}$ and the boundary data is $C^{1,\alpha}(\partial\Omega)$. Look into Gilbarg and Trudinger for the chapter on *the Schauder Approach*.

Comment: Sorry, for higher regularity I meant for the solution to the parabolic problem, but I guess this also depends on the smoothness of the eigenfunctions?

Comment: For the parabolic problem, solved through a Fourier  series, you can see that the solutions remain in the domain of every power of $\Delta$. So interior regularity is never a problem. The solution operator is a holomorphic $C_{0}$ semigroup, which just means that the power series in the time variable extends into the complex domain for $t > 0$. But I think the boundary behavior will still depend on the best that you have for the eigenfunctions.

Comment: Note: always be aware that normal derivative conditions may require compatibility conditions. I was reminded that recently again, and had forgotten. The divergence theorem relates $f$ to $g$ if the condition is purely a normal derivative. Schauder theory addresses the appropriate conditions, of course.

Comment: Wouldn't $f$ and $g$ be related only if $\partial u/\partial n=g$, I didn't think that the right hand side and initial condition were linked by divergence theorem?

Comment: unless you mean the compatibility conditions that are needed for higher regularity, such as $f(0)=Lg(0)$ (or something along those lines)

Comment: I was thinking in terms of the ellptic, $\Delta u = f$, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}u=g$. Sorry.

Comment: No worries, this is an important point :) With regards to the eigenfunctions, do you think it is possible to have global $\varphi_k\in H^2(\Omega)$, if $\Omega$ is only Lipschitz?

Comment: in fact $\Omega$ can be piecewise smooth

Comment: Yes, I expect that, but my may not get much on $\overline{\Omega}$. If you start with $C^{\infty}$ with $0$ normal derivative, then $(-\Delta f,f) = \|\nabla f\|^{2}$. So the domain of the closure is a subspace of $H^{2}$, and I think this operator is selfadjoint. You probably need $\partial\Omega$ to be piecewise smooth, however, in order to apply the Divergence Theorem, unless you know an extension to Lipschitz.

Comment: I see, so I can get higher domain regularity, but not higher boundary regularity of the solution, so I could expect the eigenfunctions to be smooth (i.e., $C^\infty(\Omega)$ but not $C^\infty(\overline{\Omega})$)? Also I thought Lipschitz was sufficient for divergence theorem? (this is not essential for what I am working on since in my problem the domain is piecewise smooth

Comment: Yes, once you get $u \in H^{2}$ and $-\Delta u = \lambda u$, then you're home free on regularity inside $\Omega$, and the eigenfunctions are in the domain of the closure of $-\Delta$ as described. I've never seen a Lipschitz extension of the divergence theorem, but that doesn't mean much.

Comment: I think in the Sobolev setting, Lipschitz boundary is enough for integration by parts/ divergence theorem

Comment: This is good news for me, I want to prove existence on unbounded domains for the mixed problem by taking a sequence of solutions in bounded domains, but I think this will require good regularity of the solutions.